# Serialize nested JSON arrays

Tags: java, json, serialization

I'd like to store `data` and `jsonFormat` in variables with `@JsonProperty`. How do I do that?

```
{
   "data": [{
             "jsonFormat": {
                 "format": "sliced",
                 "rules": [{ "key": ["NM_OBS"], "sliceName": "FCT_CONS"}]
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create classes which have the following structure

```
class AnyName {
    private List<JsonFormat> data;
}

class JsonFormat {
    private String format;
    private List<Map<String, Object>> rules;
}
```

Add the getters and setters and then just use Jackson or GSON to serialize/deserialize the data.
If you want the rules to be something more specific than `Map<String, Object>` then you can create a custom deserializer and have a Rules interface which is sub-typed.